# Remix.run - common shared components

Tags: remix.run

I’m just getting started learning remix.run and whilst I’ve gone through the tutorials there’s one bit I’m stuck on how I should implement it in remix.

If I wanted to display a common header that might toggle a sign in/sign out button based on the users logged in state where would this live?

My nextjs thinking would be to create the components and reference them in the common document. I know I can do this in the remix.server and remix.client files, but as my “login” component is and isn’t a route (I.e I might want to POST to the route when a user submits the login form but GET /login isn’t really a route) how would you structure something like this and would doing this even allow me to have loader and action functions in the shared component?

Do I just need to adjust my thinking about how to achieve this in remix or am I overthinking it and the above is perfectly valid?

I tried the following and it works. But then I end up just creating an empty "logout" route to process the form data with an `action` and `loader` that process the form in the case of the action or just redirect if a `GET` request via the loader. Is this the best approach?

```
export const SignIn = ({user}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <form method="POST"action="/logout">
            <input type="hidden" id="some" value="foo" />
        {user ? 
           (
                <button>sign out</button>
            )
        :  (
                <button>sign in</button>
            )
        }
        </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#build-the-login-form
it does indeed look like an empty route for logout:

```js
import type { ActionFunction, LoaderFunction } from "@remix-run/node"
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node"
import { logout } from "~/utils/session.server"

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({request}) => {
  return logout(request);
};

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async () => {
  return redirect("/");
};
```